# Prove that a graph of minimum degree at least $k \geq 2$ containing no triangles contains a cycle of length at least $2k$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that a graph of minimum degree at least $k \geq 2$ containing no triangles contains a cycle of length at least $2k$

I tried to use induction on $k$.
I assume when $k=n$, the statement is true.
I do not know how to construct a cycle of length $2(n+1)$ when $k=n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a triangle-free graph of minimum degree $k\geq 2$, and let $P = v_1v_2 \dots v_l$ be a longest path in $G$. All neighbours of $v_1$ are in $P$, of which there are at least $k$. Moreover, any neighbours of $v_1$ are not consecutive on $P$, since $G$ is triangle free. The index of the last neighbour of $v_1$ in $P$ is at least $2k$, which occurs if $v_1$ has $k$ neighbours, and is adjacent to $v_2, v_4, v_6, \dots, v_{2k}$. Then $v_1v_2\dots v_{2k}$ is a cycle of length $2k$ as desired.